# Finding the positive real roots of a generated polynomial

Tags: functions, function-construction, scoping

```
wlines = {427.397, 431.958, 450.235, 557.029, 587.092, 605.613, 
       645.629, 665.223, 669.923, 681.311, 690.468};
wcal = {4.1989123474370302*^02,-5.3957450948852408*^-02,6.7152505835315814*^-04,-8.6698204011228679*^-07,*^5.5523712684399200*^-10}


(* define wavelength to pixel module *)
g[x_] := Expand[FromDigits[Reverse[wcal], x]];
WTP[wave_, guess_] := Module[{g, y, PolyDeriv, delta, ans, current},
  PolyDeriv = D[g[y], y];
  delta = 1.0;
  ans = guess;
  current = g[ans] - wave;
  While[Abs[current] > 0.00001,
    ans = ans - (current/(PolyDeriv /. y -> ans));

   current = g[ans] - wave;
   Return[ans]
   (* we never reach this point to return NULL *)
   ]

  ](* end module *)

(* check module *)
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[wlines], i++,
 Print[WTP[wlines[[i]], 500]]
 ]
```

1. I have a function defined, which takes in a set of wavelengths and computes an approximate pixel value with respect to a Polynomial generated from a set of coefficients `g[x_]`. PolyDeriv is the first order derivative of `g[x_]`. For some reason, the result from this function is returning NULL, where in it should give a list of pixel index values.
2. Will it be any different if I define function `g[x_]` inside the Module `WTP` ?

Comment: Remove `g` from the list of local variables at the beginning of `Module`. That is at least one problem.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your definition of `wcal`. Towards its end, you either have one too many `*^`, or a value is missing. If I remove the spurious `*^` and remove `g` from the local variable of the module, then your code at least returns some numbers.

Comment: Suggest that you define `g[x_] = HornerForm[FromDigits[Reverse[wcal], x]];`  and `dg[x_] = HornerForm[D[g[x], x]];` for faster evaluation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code can be much simplified. The following rewrite of your code works.

```
wlines = 
  {427.397, 431.958, 450.235, 557.029, 587.092, 605.613, 
   645.629, 665.223, 669.923, 681.311, 690.468};
wcal = 
  {4.1989123474370302*^02, -5.3957450948852408*^-02, 6.7152505835315814*^-04, 
   -8.6698204011228679*^-07, 5.5523712684399200*^-10};

g[x_] = HornerForm[FromDigits[Reverse[wcal], x]];
dg[x_] = HornerForm[D[g[x], x]];

WTP[wave_, guess_] :=
  Module[{ans, current},
    ans = guess;
    current = g[ans] - wave;
    While[Abs[current] > 0.00001, 
      ans = ans - current/dg[ans];
      current = g[ans] - wave];
    ans]

WTP[#, 500] & /@ wlines
```

> ```
>  {179.433, 215.412, 327.804, 725.683, 793.985, 830.215, 897.144, 
>   925.497, 931.944, 947.049, 958.703}
> ```

After simplification I conclude that you are solving `g[x] == lines[[i]]` by the Newton-Raphson method. But why not do it the easy way using the built-in function `NSolve`:

```
 (NSolve[g[x] == #, x, Reals] & /@ wlines)[[All, 2]][[All, 1, 2]]
```

> ```
>  {179.433, 215.412, 327.804, 725.683, 793.985, 830.215, 897.144, 
>   925.497, 931.944, 947.049, 958.703}
> ```

Comment: I dint realize it was Newton Raphson Method. Your solution is very productive.